# Heterogeneous pointer container

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently using an enum to map into an array of Base*.  Each Derived type is given an index by the enum.

```
enum DerivedType {
    DERIVED_TYPE_1 = 0,
    DERIVED_TYPE_2,
    ...
    NUM_DERIVED_TYPES
};


class Base {

};


class Derived1 : public Base {
    static const DerivedType type;
};
const DerivedType Derived1::type = DERIVED_TYPE_1;


class Derived2 : public Base {
    static const DerivedType type;
};
const DerivedType Derived2::type = DERIVED_TYPE_2;


class Container {
    Base* obs[NUM_DERIVED_TYPES];

    template<class T>
    void addOb(T* ob) {
        obs[T::type] = ob;
    }

    template<class T>
    T* getOb() {
        return (T*) obs[T::type];
    }

    Base* getOb(DerivedType type) {
        return obs[type];
    }
};
```

Since the index of each derived type is known at compile time, is there a way to have the non-template `getOb(DerivedType type)` return the correct DerivedN pointer, maybe by looking up the typename in an int -> typename map?  Or is there a better way to implement this type of pattern?  Also, it would be nice to have each Derived type add itself to whatever data structure assigns it its index value.

Basically, I need a static heterogeneous pointer container that can be accessed by type or by index, all the while returning the correct Derived*.  I'm guessing Boost has something that would work, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm not 100% confident that I understand the question correctly,
probably what you mentioned(or similar one) can be implemented
with `boost::fusion` and `boost::mpl`.
For example:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_key.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
namespace bf = boost::fusion;
namespace bm = boost::mpl;

// This order has to match with the enumerators in DerivedType
typedef bm::vector< Derived1, Derived2 > DerivedTypes;

typedef bf::map< bf::pair< Derived1, Derived1* >
               , bf::pair< Derived2, Derived2* > > Container;

int main() {
    Container c( bf::make_pair< Derived1, Derived1* >(0)
               , bf::make_pair< Derived2, Derived2* >(0) );
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    bf::at_key< Derived1 >( c ) = &d1; // access with type
    bf::at_key< Derived2 >( c ) = &d2;
    // access with enum
    bf::at_key< bm::at_c< DerivedTypes, DERIVED_TYPE_1 >::type >( c ) = &d1;
    bf::at_key< bm::at_c< DerivedTypes, DERIVED_TYPE_2 >::type >( c ) = &d2;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for, thanks. One improvement I made is to have the map automatically populated from the vector: `typedef bm::fold<DerivedTypes, bf::map<>, bm::push_back<bm::_1, bf::pair<bm::_2, boost::add_pointer<bm::_2> > > >::type Container;`

Answer (score 0):

(1) `is there a way to have the "non-template" getOb(DerivedType type) return the correct DerivedN pointer`

Unfortunately not possible. For non-template functions, a return type can be only a single type and that has to be `Base*` type in your case. Current implementation of `Base* getOb(DerivedType type);` is proper.

(2) `is there a better way to implement this type of pattern?`

At least you can ease your work by using templatized intermediate class (without any overhead), which will initialize the `DerivedType` variable for you. For example, declare something like below:

```
template<DerivedType TYPE>
struct Link : Base {
  static const DerivedType type;
};
template<DerivedType TYPE>
const DerivedType Link<TYPE>::type = TYPE;
```

Now `Link<DerivedType>` should be inherited for the Derived classes, such as:

```
class Derived1 : public Link<DERIVED_TYPE_1> {
// no need to declare/define an explicit variable for DerivedType now.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you currently have looks pretty solid to me. The only problem I see, is that you'll only have a `Base*` available at runtime, since a single function can only return 1 type. To allow multi-type return without having to specify an extra parameter, you could fake a function like so:

```
// if employed as a free function
class getOb{
  DerivedType _type;
public:
  getOb(DerivedType type)
    : _type(type) {}

  template<class T>
  operator T*() const{
    Base* ptr;
    // fetch correct pointer from wherever
    // using _type, if non-existant use 0
    return (T*) ptr;
  }
};
```

Usage like

```
Derived1* pd = getOb(DERIVED_TYPE_1);
assert(pd != 0);
```

The parameter is passed in the constructor, while the actual function body lies in the conversion operator. Of course this only looks good as a free standing function, so here is how it would look if you wanted to implement it as a member function

```
class GetObClass{
  mutable DerivedType _type;
public:
  GetObClass& operator()(DerivedType type) const{
    _type = type;
    return *this;
  }

  // template conversion operator as before
};
```

Usage like

```
class Container{
public:
  const GetObClass getOb;
};

Container c;
Derived1* pd = c.getOb(DERIVED_TYPE_1);
assert(pd != 0);
```